# Go, not getting string value

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {

    // Just count the files...
    systems,_ := ioutil.ReadDir("./XML")
    fmt.Printf("# of planetary systems\t%d\r\n", len(systems))

    // For each datafile
    for _,element := range systems {
        fmt.Println(element.Name)
    }

}
```

This line...

```
fmt.Println(element.Name)
```

Is outputting a memory address instead of what I assume to be the filename string. Why? How do I get the actual string? Thanks.

Also all the addresses are the same, I would expect them to difer, meaning my for-each loop might be broken.

Comment: Please work through the "Tour of Go" at least twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FileInfo.Name`](https://godoc.org/os#FileInfo) is a function of the `FileInfo` interface; the function's memory address is being printed. To display the name of the file, you need to evaluate the function before printing:

```
for _, element := range systems {
    fmt.Println(element.Name())
}
```

Comment: Works great now, thx. You'll get the answer when the timer expires.